# Closed form geometric series for complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, geometric-series

Say I want to express the following series of complex numbers using a closed expression:
$$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(r\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ix}\right)^n.$$
If we interpret the summands the same way as real numbers then we may derive such an expression:
$$\left(1-r\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ix}\right)S(x)=1\iff S(x)=\frac1{1-r\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ix}},$$
and I "know" this holds if
$$\left|r\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ix}\right|=r<1.$$
But, I cannot really show why this in fact holds for complex numbers, in particular why the convergence condition $\left|r\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ix}\right|<1$ makes sense (the requirement that the summands being less then one in case of real numbers is clear). I tried to write
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(2n\pi x)+\mathrm i\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \sin(2n\pi x),$$
but didn't manage to make progress.

Comment: rather than thinking of this as an extension from real to complex, think of it as an initially complex concept. This is called the "radius of convergence"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remember how the proof of the convergence and sum for a *real* geometric series goes, that proof works directly for the complex case too.

The first part of the proof concludes that
$$ s_k = \sum_{n=0}^k c^n = \frac{1-c^{k+1}}{1-c} $$
and this part depends only on the field axioms, so it works just as well in $\mathbb C$ as it does in $\mathbb R$.

The next part takes the limit of this expression as $k\to\infty$, and what you need there is just that $c^{k+1}\to 0$ when $|c|<1$. That's a simple consequence of the fact that the complex absolute value is compatible with multiplication, so (by induction on $k$ if you insist on strict formality) $|c^{k+1}| = |c|^{k+1} \to 0$.

---

A different way to think about it is that the real and complex part of each term in $\sum_n (re^{2\pi ix})^n$ is absolutely bounded by $r^n$ -- so if $r<1$, then the real and complex parts of the sum converge separately by the comparison test.

This argument is more general and leads to the idea of a disc of convergence in general.